# creating a function to alias linux

Tags: linux, terminal, alias

### Background

I am pretty new to Linux and using aliases.
I understand that in order to add a permanent alias, I need to edit the .bashrc file and I've doing this a lot.
I was wondering if there is a way I could just add an alias permenantly
Without having to open the file and actually adding it.

### Current knowledge

I did some research and learned I could give an alias to a function,
And that function could get parameters (the alias I want to add each time)
But I still don't know where I can write this function.

### The question

My question is how exactly do I create an alias for a function, and where do I write it.
Also if you can explain to me the syntax of those functions I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Clarification

I decided to answer this old quiestion of mine
To contribute the solution I finally went with.

#### The solution

- First thing I did after some research, was to move
  My aliases to `.bash_aliases` file.
  This helped my keep an organized and minimal `.bashrc`
  And gather togeter all of my aliases.
- Secondly, in order to achieve adding an alias permanently and without
  having to reopen and edit .bashrc file I added a function in `.bash_aliases`

#### Function guidlines

- Handle terminal arguments
  This function received an argument of format:
  'new_alias=commands'
- Append the new alias received to .bash_aliases
- Source `.bash_aliases` file to include new aliases added to the current terminal window.
- Handle modification of aliases:
  If an alias with the same name was received, sed was used to replace
  The commands executed in 'alias'

Answer (score 0):

```
function_name () { command1 command2 }

function_name () { command1 p1 command2 p1}
```

Example

```
nd () {
    mkdir -p $1
    cd $1
}
```

Add this to bashrc, and then `nd <folder>` 
create a new folder and move into that.

Comment: i just add this exact code some where in the bashrc file? i tried doing so and got an error

Comment: yes you have to add this code to .bashrc open a new shell and you can use this function.

Comment: @Yarden where is the error?